# Does the air gap between the metal target and coil in an inductive position sensor change the position value?

Tags: electromagnetism, inductive, position-sensor

I am trying to design an inductive position sensor with the inductive sensor IC [ZMID5201](https://www.mouser.in/datasheet/2/464/IDT_ZMID520x-Datasheet_DST_20180528-1222664.pdf).

[image]

I am trying to optimize the air gap betweeen sensor coil and metal target. The datasheet mentions that the output signal remains stable even if the gap between sensor coils and target is varied.

Can anyone explain the theory behind this constant output signal?

[image]

Comment: Why are you so shy about supplying the part number, datasheet link and Figure 3 from the article?

Comment: sorry I am not shy about giving the part number, its mentioned the datasheets are secured.                
 https://www.mouser.in/datasheet/2/464/IDT_ZMID520x-Datasheet_DST_20180528-1222664.pdf

Comment: That information belongs in the question, not in the comments. See the update.

Answer (score 0):

You can find lots of theory if you look for resolver. It's the same principle, then you'll understand that if you divide two secondary signals the amplitude doesn't matter, since both are weakened with same magnitude.

$$V_{sec_{sin}} = K\cdot V_{prim}\cdot sin\varphi$$
$$V_{sec_{cos}} = K\cdot V_{prim}\cdot cos\varphi$$
$$tg\varphi = \dfrac{K\cdot V_{prim}\cdot sin\varphi}{K\cdot V_{prim}\cdot cos\varphi} $$
$$V_{prim} = V_{exc}\cdot sin\omega t$$
$$tg\varphi = \dfrac{K\cdot V_{exc}\cdot sin\omega t\cdot sin\varphi}{K\cdot V_{exc}\cdot sin\omega t\cdot cos\varphi} = \dfrac{ sin\varphi}{cos\varphi}$$

Theoretically the coupling factor K and voltage amplitude has no influence, practically it has since the AD converter has a working range.

Comment: https://www.mouser.in/datasheet/2/464/IDT_ZMID520x-Datasheet_DST_20180528-1222664.pdf. thank you for your response. this is the data sheet link for the above question. Page 9.